# How to achieve 50 Ohm Impedance with a SMB connector

Tags: rf, high-frequency, high-speed

I have a PCB design with a [SMB connector](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-Linx-Technologies/CONSMB003.062-G?qs=81r%252BiQLm7BS1x%252Bddqyjtvw%3D%3D) but can't find any information about how I should treat the pad to ensure 50R impedance.

Should there be a keepout on the ground layer directly beneath this top signal layer except in the area the trace runs across the pad?[image: SMB Connector on PCB]

In accordance with manufacturer guidelines, FB5_1 needs a ground keepout on the pad touching the high speed trace to ensure there is no impedance mismatch. This would lead me to believe that the SMB pad also requires a ground keepout but I can't be sure.

The board is a 6 layer design (SIG-GND pairs) with nothing on the ground plane directly underneath these high speed signal traces.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the track that goes upwards and off to the right from the resistor that connects to the track that feeds the connector.

Comment: This where you may have to use a 3-D EM modeling tool.  Intuitively, if the trace going up away from the connector is 50 ohms, then the pad cannot be 50 ohms (assuming a ground plane beneath it) since it is 3 or 4 times wider than the trace.

Comment: Andy - Could you clarify your point? From my understanding (which could be wrong), in this particular design, the -ve trace should be loosely coupled to the +ve trace in a single ended configuration and terminated through a 49.9R resistor to ground near the connector. The IC can also be used in a differential signal configuration but a SMB works better for this design.

Comment: Steve - Thanks for your comment. It certainly makes sense that it would create an impedance mismatch. I suppose the "extent" of impedance mismatch can only really be captured in a simulation or by measuring the insertion loss of the PCB itself.

Comment: If sinusoidal, what is the max frequency that you want the SMB to work to? If digital, what is the risetime (not clock rate) of the signal. This will tell us whether you need to worry about this level of matching, it may be a non-problem.

Comment: @CT123 if you posted a schematic it makes it easier to explain. You need to use the "at" symbol in front of a user name to get their attention when responding. I only came across your comment randomly.